# receive $_POST variables from jquery ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I am making an ajax request that looks like

```
 var object = JSON.stringify(object);
// var url = "http://"+baseURL +"/"+endpoint;

$.ajax({
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json',
    type:type,
    data:object,
    url:endpoint,
    success:function(data){
        if (typeof callback == "function"){
            alert(data);
        }
    },

    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(xhr.statusText);
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(xhr.status);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

where `var=object` is a stringified json objectby the time it makes it into the ajax request. On the php side, I am trying to catch the variables by doing

```
<?php
   echo ($_POST['object']);
   exit;
?>
```

and my success call back function alerts the data as "null". What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
alex

Comment: Exactly where is `type` defined? if that's not `POST`, then you're not doing a post...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath yes it is, my type comes in from a wrapper function as "POST"

Comment: still getting null...What should my php look like? I have echo ($_POST['object']);

Comment: Can you `var_dump($_POST)` ?

Comment: OK api.js:35
array(4) {
  ["ReviewID"]=>
  string(4) "1009"
  ["Comment"]=>
  string(6) "asdasd"
  ["UserID"]=>
  string(7) "1000001"
  ["ArtworkID"]=>
  string(7) "1000010"
}
 api.js:36
200 api.js:37
SyntaxError {} api.js:38
z

Comment: which means it's not entering the error: callback of the ajax request

Comment: echoing echo json_encode($_POST{'Comment'});
now returns the correct variables for some reason, so does that mean all I need to do now is store them locally like $Comment = $_POST["Comment"];?

Comment: Yes, exactly you should do this with decoded data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip the json.stringify you don't want the data as json text in the post body. To populate the post array it needs to be sent as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. To do this in jquery just set the data attribute to an object instead of a string.

```
// remove this.... var object = JSON.stringify(object);
// var url = "http://"+baseURL +"/"+endpoint;

$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    type:"POST",  // <--- Should be post
    data:object,
    url:endpoint,
    success:function(data){
        if (typeof callback == "function"){
            alert(data);
        }
    },

    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(xhr.statusText);
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(xhr.status);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

It is possible to get the data as you are sending it currently but you have to go through a little more work on the PHP side.

```
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
```

Comment: you can just omit it or set it to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (which is what is sent if you don't set a contenttype)